# Issue with query in st_read()

Tags: r, r-sp, r-sf

I am new to sf package and trying to read shapefile and subset it based on the query. Here, I used sf_read()

```
  load <- st_read(dsn = "~Data", layer = "CBSA_MetroDiv", 
            query = "select * from CBSA_MetroDiv limit 3;")
```

but its throwing an error as

```
Reading layer `CBSA_MetroDiv' from data source `\Data' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'

Error in st_sf(x, ..., agr = agr, sf_column_name = sf_column_name) : 
no simple features geometry column present
```

can someone guide me on this issue.

Comment: Does it work without all the other arguments, like `load <- st_read("path/to/your/shape/file.shp")`

Comment: yes. It's working with out query, but throwing an error when I add query. my goal is to load only subset of shape file instead of loading whole shape file into memory.

Comment: Have done some tests, and asked here: https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/834 otherwise check the VRT workaround in the answer.

Answer (score 7):

## Update: `query` now implemented

The `query` option should now work for GDAL/OGR data sources.

Without `query`:

```
> s = st_read(f)
Reading layer `uk_LAD_may_2020_with_insets_v1.1' from data source 
  `/nobackup/rowlings/Downloads/uk_LAD_may_2020_with_insets_v1.1.shp' 
  using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
Simple feature collection with 464 features and 9 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -87544.11 ymin: 5344.479 xmax: 980803.6 ymax: 1220302
Projected CRS: OSGB 1936 / British National Grid
```

gets 464 features. With query (and I have quote up the layer name because its got dots in it, you may not need to):

```
> s = st_read(f, query="select * from \"uk_LAD_may_2020_with_insets_v1.1\" where scale = 3")
Reading query `select * from "uk_LAD_may_2020_with_insets_v1.1" where scale = 3' from data source `/nobackup/rowlings/Downloads/uk_LAD_may_2020_with_insets_v1.1.shp' 
  using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
Simple feature collection with 52 features and 9 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -87544.11 ymin: 146818.5 xmax: 949029.8 ymax: 986035
Projected CRS: OSGB 1936 / British National Grid
```

Only 52 features.

## Previous Answer: for older `sf` package versions only:

The `query` option is only mentioned in the documentation for class `DBIObject`, for the "default S3" method there's no `query` parameter, so your query string is being passed into the `...` argument which ends up being passed to `st_as_sf` and then at some later point it throws a spanner in the works.

There may be a way round, but one solution is to create a virtual data set file with the SQL in it. For example, I have a shapefile of French postal regions, and here is a virtual data set file called `filter.vrt` which applies an SQL select:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="points">
        <SrcDataSource relativeToVRT="1">codes_postaux_region.shp</SrcDataSource>
        <SrcSQL>select * from codes_postaux_region where POP2010 > 20000</SrcSQL>
 </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

Create a similar file for your shapefile and SQL using a plain text editor, and then read it. Here you can see i get 6048 features if I read the shapefile, but only 707 when I read the virtual data file:

```
> fr = st_read("./codes_postaux_region.shp",quiet=TRUE)
> nrow(fr)
[1] 6048
> fr = st_read("./filter.vrt",quiet=TRUE)
> nrow(fr)
[1] 707
```

You might need to set the coordinate system on the filtered data set, either after reading it in if you know it or possibly via another VRT file parameter.

Might be worth pinging Edzer to see if SQL in `st_read` for shapefiles can be implemented or if I've missed something. I *feel* there's a way of telling `st_read` what the geometry column is...